# Symfony Collection Validation

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-validator

I've building a quick API with Symfony 6.1 and custom validators to validate my inputs, and I'm struggling with the syntax.

I made this:

```
$constraint = new Collection([
            'fields' => [
                'discordId' => [
                    new Type(['type' => 'numeric']),
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
                'discordHandle' => [
                    new Type(['type' => 'string']),
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Regex([
                        'pattern' => '/^((.{2,32})#\d{4})/',
                        'message' => 'Please provide a valid Discord handle (eg. USERNAME#1234).',
                    ]),
                ],
                'pictureUrls' => [
                    new Type(['type' => 'array']),
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Count(['min' => 1, 'max' => 5]),
                    //new Url(),
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

It works fine until I re-enable the Url() constraint, then it expects the "pictureUrls" fields to be a string and not an array anymore.

My syntax must be wrong but I don't understand how I can make it to expect "pictureUrls" to be an array containing Urls.

Can anyone help, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html) right, I'm pretty sure you wan to do:

```
            'pictureUrls' => [
                new Type(['type' => 'array']),
                new NotBlank(),
                new Count(['min' => 1, 'max' => 5]),
                new All([
                    new Url(),
                ])
            ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I set your code instead of mine but now I've got:
`"propertyPath" => "[pictureUrls][1]"
 "message" => "This value should be of type array|\Countable."`

And only for [1], while I sent an array of 5 elements. Pretty strange

Comment: what is the data you are actually sending in?

Comment: `pictureUrls[]:https://www.fake.com/picture1.jpg
pictureUrls[]:https://www.fake.com/picture2.jpg
pictureUrls[]:https://www.fake.com/picture3.jpg
discordUserId:13371337
discordHandle:Fake#1337
`

Sorry it's hard to format in the comments section

Comment: ah ok, sorry, I think if you look at the most recent edit it should work, `All` should run the validation for each element in the array https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html